# UDP Broadcast answer

Tags: sockets, tcp, udp, broadcast

While making a network app I met following problem.

In this scenario there are you and multiple servers in a local network to connect to, you can choose which one. Between you and the selected server there should be a TCP connection in the end.

I found UDP broadcast to be really convenient on one side but how do I answer the broadcast (I need to send some information back)? Basicly I see two possibilites.

1. to make a lot TCP connections
2. to add an UDP sender and listener.

How would you solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a UDP listener to the server. When it receives a UDP request, send a reply back to the sender's IP/Port, and have that reply including the server's listening TCP IP/Port.  The client can then send a broadcast, wait a few seconds to collect all of the replies, present them to the user, and then make a TCP connection to the selected server.